# Question on a Proof from C* Algebras by Murphy

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I'm reading through the following theorem and it's proof and I have a question on the last part.  The theorem is the following:

Theorem: Let $u \in B(H_1,H_2)$ for $H_{1,2}$ Hilbert spaces.  Then the following are equivalent.

1. $u=uu^{*}u$
2. $u^{*}u$ is a projection
3. $uu^{*}$ is a projection
4. $u|_{(\text{ker} \: u)^{\perp}}$ is isometric

I'm having an issue with the implication $(4) \rightarrow (2)$.  They give the following proof:

Suppose that $u|_{(\text{ker} \: u)^{\perp}}$ is isometric. Let $p: H_1 \longrightarrow (\text{ker} \: u)^{\perp}$ be the projection of $H_1$ onto $(\text{ker} \: u)^{\perp}$.  Then for $x \in (\text{ker} \: u)^{\perp}$: $$\langle u^{*}u(x),x \rangle = ||u(x)||^2 = \langle x,x\rangle = \langle p(x),x \rangle \implies \langle u^{*}u(x)-p(x),x \rangle = 0.$$ If $x \in \text{ker} \: u$, then $\langle u^{*}u(x),x \rangle = 0 = \langle p(x),x \rangle$.  Hence $$\langle u^{*}u(x)-p(x),x \rangle =0 \: \: \text{for all $x \in H_1$} \implies u^{*}u=p.$$  I don't understand this last implication.  We've shown for every specific $x \in H_1$, that $u^{*}u(x)-p(x) \perp x$.  Since the difference $(u^{*}u-p)(x)$ clearly depends on $x$, we can't simply say that $(u^{*}u-p)(x) \in H_1^{\perp} = \{0\}$, since we don't know if for instance there exists $x \in H_1$ and some $y \in H_1 \setminus \{x\}$ with $\langle u^{*}u(x)-p(x),y \rangle \neq 0$.

Can someone help me understand their reasoning?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is a bounded operator on a *complex* Hilbert space $H$ such that $\langle a\xi,\xi\rangle=0$ for all $\xi\in H$, then $a=0$.

Indeed, by the polarization identity,
$$
4\langle a\xi,\eta\rangle=\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k\langle a(\xi+i^k\eta),\xi+i^k\eta\rangle,
$$
and the right side is zero for all $\xi,\eta\in H$.

Comment: Ah I totally forgot about the polarization identity, thank you!